# How to assign to the array of pointers functions from another object?

Tags: c++, function, class, pointers

I defined

```
int(*Functions[3])();

int select(){
cout<<"SELECT!";
getchar();
}
```

Now i want to assign a function to 'Functions', and when i do like this:

```
Functions[0]=select;
Functions[0];
```

It works, but i want to assign function 'select' from my own object

```
class worker{
HERE DEFINED FUNCTION
}

worker object1;
Functions[0]=object1.select;
```

It doesn't work. "use '&' to create a pointer to member", " '=':cannot convert from 'int(_thiscall worker::*)(void)' to 'int(_cdecl*)(void)'"

I don't know a differences between using

```
select();
object1.select();
```

Comment: A pointer to non-member function cannot be used for it.

Comment: Why not? Can you explain?

Comment: can you use a pointer to int to point to a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pointer to member function cannot be used for a non-member function and vice-versa. If you want then create another one for a member function in your example.

```
class Foo{
    public:
        void func(){
            cout << "Foo::func()" << endl;
        }
};

void func2(){
    cout << "func2()" << endl;
}


int main(){

    void(*pFunc[3])();
    pFunc[0] = func2;

    void(Foo::*pFunc2[3])();
    pFunc2[0] = &Foo::func;

    Foo theFoo; // You need an object to call it
    (theFoo.*(pFunc2[0]))(); // calling the member function

    return 0;
}
```

In addition as @Serge's useful comment:

pointer to a member function requires knowledge of a type of the encapsulating object and an instance of an object at the time it is used. Therefore it is not a simple pointer which you can use for static function only (including static function defined within a class).

Comment: pointer to a member function requires knowledge of a type of the encapsulating object and an instance of an object at the time it is used.  Therefore it is not a simple pointer. The simple pointer you can use for static function only (including static function defined within a class). The latter might be just an address of the function in the memory.

Comment: It works, but one more question, how to call this function?

Comment: @Serge: Thank you for your useful comment.

Comment: If you can, last question. How to send this array as an argument to a function and then how to work on elements of this array?

Comment: Please ask a new question.

Comment: `void print( void(Foo::*pFunc[])(), int size ){
  Foo f;
  for(int i(0); i != size; ++i)
   (f.*pFunc[i])();
 }`

Comment: I created an array of pointers for functions as you wrote above. Now I want to use this table, sending it as an argument to the function and working on it

Comment: you can also pass the object `f` to function not just declaring it inside the function.